# How insert value to database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is my migration

```
create_table :customers do |t|
  t.string "name", :limit => 25 , :null => false
  t.string "email", :limit => 25, :null => false
  t.string "question", :limit => 255 , :null => true
  t.integer "status", :limit => 1, :default => 0, :null => false
  t.timestamps
end
```

Now, in the model, I want insert a value using this code:

```
Customers.new(:name => name, :email => email, :question => question, :status => 1)
```

But value does not inserted in table, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you haven't actually **saved** it.

```
customer = Customer.new(:name => name, :email => email, :question => question, :status => 1)
if custom.save
  // Saved succefully
else
  // Failed to save
end
```

Or just use `create` instead

```
customer = Customer.create!(:name => name, :email => email, :question => question, :status => 1)
```

With bang after `create`, it should raise an error if failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert in a line you need to use **create** method like below

```
Customers.create(:name => name, :email => email, :question => question, :status => 1)
```

Otherwise you need to create new object then need to use the save method to create a new record in DB, like below

```
customer = Customers.new(:name => name, :email => email, :question => question, :status => 1)
customer.save
```

If you need more clarification, let me know.